# Changing image gallery output HTML

Tags: php, wordpress

Wordpress provides `" Add Media "` feature where you can add an image gallery.

I am replicating few steps how we do that.

[image]

[image]

[image]

When the default WordPress theme is installed this is how it looks like →

[image]

## Question:

Just like we customize the default WordPress comment system in the front end how can we customize this for the gallery the way we want to look this in the front-end?

## Update →

`<div class="entry-content">`
Currently everything is coming under the above div. how can we change the whole HTML structure?

Comment: What do you mean by change the whole html structure? You can edit easily in the theme's folder

Answer (score -1):

You can edit your theme in the theme folder. Go to the root of your WordPress. Then go to `/wp-content/themes/your_theme`.

Here you should find different templates such as :

```
post.php => the generic page template
single.php => the generic template for news
archive.php => the generic template for listing of news
```

Those 3 should fit your needs. Edit the HTML inside those files to get what you need !

Comment: Do you actually understand the question?

Comment: `how can we customize this for the gallery the way we want to look this in the front-end` I supposed you wanted to make some HTML / CSS to do your updates...